# Why do I have no sound when resuming from sleep, but if I plug in then remove headphones sound returns?

Tags: 11.10, sound, alsa, volume-control

I am having strange issues with sound and volume with Ubuntu 11.10

I've noticed very often, especially when I get my computer out of sleep, it lacks sound even though the volume slider is cranked all the way up, but when I plug my headphones in and then take them out, it seems to kick start my sound back!

What gives?

What daemon in `/etc/int.d` needs to be restared with the `restart` command to fix this?

I have the following in my `init.d` folder

`/etc/init.d/alsa-restore` and `/etc/init.d/alsa-store`

Also, my start up Ubuntu sound doesn't play either....

Comment: Did you remove pulseaudio or changed settings in its default.pa?

Comment: @Takkat Thats very likely. Is there anything else that could have caused it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I plug hadphone jack (in Ubuntu 11.10). I found `pacmd` command that show console

```
$ pacmd
Welcome to PulseAudio! Use "help" for usage information.
```

I run this

```
>>> list-sinks
```

and it returns that second sink (I have hdmi and analog stero) was mute

```
muted: yes
```

so I call (help will show all the commands).

```
>>> set-sink-mute 1 false
```

and it enabled the sound (before that I restarted puleaudio - `$ sudo /etc/init.d/pulseaudio` but I think it was not needed).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that works so far is to `killall pusleaudio` and then restarting it back again. This seems to be an issue with Ubuntu 11.10 as I've had friends describe the same problem.